# Exam document class - Question numbering and questionlabel

Tags: exam

I am trying to format the question number in the exam class, I want the word "Question" and the question number in bold but the question itself in normal text.

Reading the Exam class document I found that the question number can be grabbed with `\thequestion` and later it says it can be obtained as well with `\thetitlequestion` if it is a `\question`, but when I try to redefine the command as following:

```
\documentclass[answers,a4paper,12pt]{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestiontitle} \quad \thequestiontitle}

\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
 \question{This is a good example}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I get the question number repeated, why? what did I misunderstand or did wrong?

[image: Current result]

At the end I will love just the question and number in bold, I tried `\qformat` but it will require an horizontal filling so it will put the question at the end.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Question \thequestiontitle}}`

Comment: Oh thanks @ferahfeza! that worked fined! So if I understand correctly, the question will be appended always anyway, isn't it?

Comment: You're welcome. Absolutely, yes.